# Window layout changes to Aero when moved into panel

Tags: forms, cmd, window, panel, aero

I use the code down below to open a cmd.exe window and move it into a panel on my form. I do this so that I can change the title permanently during execution.
When cmd.exe is started, the window layout looks like this:
[image]
Which is the standard Windows 10 layout. But as soon as it's moved into the panel in my form, the window layout changes to the old Aero layout:
[image]
I don't know why the layout changes, does anybody know why?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Kind regards,
Eric

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents Tmr As New Timer With {.Interval = 100}
    Private Const HWND_BOTTOM As Integer = &H1
    Private WithEvents proc As New Process
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetParent")>
    Private Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowPos")>
    Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "My title"
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
        proc.Start()
        Tmr.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
        If SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle) <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Tmr.Stop()
            SetWindowPos(proc.MainWindowHandle, New IntPtr(HWND_BOTTOM), 0, 0, Panel1.ClientSize.Width, Panel1.ClientSize.Height, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Proc_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles proc.Exited
        Invoke(Sub() Close())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be related to the way a MDI child is handled. Since MDI is no longer maintained, this issue will probably never be fixed by Microsoft.